# How to make a custom directive for reusing html attributes?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular 1.7.x. I want to move the common stuff of the 2 input fields to a directive to reduce boilerplate. Is there a way to create a custom directive for this?

```
<tbody>     
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in advHistoryList"
        <td class="lh-adv-hist-td" ng-if="isFlagTrue">
             <input
                type="image"                                   
                class="global-icon global-icon-edit"
                value = "{{obj.comment}}"
                title={{HOVER_FOR_DETAILS}}
                ng-disabled="isThisSelected(obj.id)"
                ng-show="obj.hastext"
                my-hover-directive />
            <input
                type="image"                                  
                class="global-icon global-icon-add"
                value = "{{obj.comment}}"
                title={{OVER_FOR_DETAILS}}
                ng-disabled="isThisSelected(obj.id)"
                ng-show="obj.addText"
                my-hover-directive />

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Comment: Since angular 1.5, component support was added. Using a component as opposed to a directive will make the migration to a more modern framework easier. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component